# Heroku login hanging in Git Bash

Tags: git, heroku, git-bash

When I try to log in from git bash it hangs for a long time, like this:

[image: an image of what happen]

I have tried the `cmd` in windows 8.1 and in comparison it works well, but when I try it in git bash it hangs.  How can I fix this?